# Firebase database snapshot returns null when I take a datasnapshot with usertoken string (sometimes), why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just started storing usertokens in my database for notification purposes. I have no problem storing and retrieving the data except with certain usertoken string values. But when I take a datasnapshot with a usertoken it returns null, only sometimes though.

My listener looks like this (just a regular listener):

```
udRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new   ValueEventListener () { 
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot datasnapshot) { 
User user = datasnapshot.get value(User.class);

//do something with data here 
//eg. Log.e("ERR", String.value Of(user));  
//returns "null" for SOME users only, keep reading.

} 
@Override
public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError) {  ... }

});
```

When a user creates an account, it automatically inserts a string token that looks like this:

`"cL_AEuSZa1I:APA91bF9R-dDetqrSNMQMzAoHRmLOHXK2acK_zJLhFhZ5IhvNChPSx4P943GirVwsy5walc0RrvyGnMm49oLxNJ-uKsGRCELhJ-9kwnPmdHOyWJWz0Esm_Y0MB7BypNUuQ4qZQmoW5nO"`

Tokens are used for push notifications using FCM. This is refreshed automatically as recommended by the FB guys. The token above isn't valid, in fact this very usertoken made my datasnapshot not work so I had to manually remove it! And yes, immediately I removed it I was able to capture the snapshot, it didn't return null anymore.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong, but when I look (with my eyes, not a script) at the usertokens in the database I can tell which ones will be troublesome. This is how:

All usertokens are too long, so Firebase's web console cuts them short like this `"gftgvdgGhbgfc_fggg..."`

All the troublesome tokens get cut also but without the 3 dots or closing quotes, they look like this  `"gftgvdgGhbgfc_fggg` but when expanded they are normal like the working ones (length is same).

I have 30 users so I can easily go through them all :D

This is how my data looks (roughly):

```
"fhgfFghDfgghhfDDf" : {
    "username" : "a_string_here"
    "userPic" : "looong_string_link_to_fb_storage"
    "usertoken" : "long_user_token_like the_one_in_question"
},...
```

Am I storing the tokens wrongly?, should I convert them to some other data type? Too many 'gotchas' in FB :(

Please note, I DO NOT have problems with anything else except the usertokens making my datasnapshot null, so any mistakes in the code are just typos (I typed this question from my phone referencing my laptop screen... don't ask)

Comment: I have problem understanding this statement "But when I take a datasnapshot with a usertoken it returns null, only sometimes though.". Have you tried calling `dataSnapshot.toString()` under `onDataChange()` to get the raw content of a dataSnapshot ? Because it's probably the usertoken field name of `User` class is not the same with the one in the database.

Comment: @Wilik I mean sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  Also I just double checked, all the fields match (case and all). `datasnapshot.toString()` gives all the raw data at that snapshot. It is hard to replicate the issue because if manually remove the buggy token and put it back, it works fine..weird

Comment: so: (1) you attach a listener to `users` node. (2) any new registered user will do `.child(uid).setValue()` to `users` node (3) the `onDataChange` method is triggered, but the `usertoken` field is missing/null in the `dataSnapshot` (4) after you delete and re-add the `usertoken` manually via the firebase console, the `usertoken` is not null anymore. is that correct? very weird haha

Comment: @Wilik pretty much, except that at your (3) the entire node goes null not just `usertoken`. It has happened to 2/10 new users so far since implementation..that's a bigger percentage than I'm comfortable with

Comment: try to attach `ChildEventListener` instead to `/users`, and then push new user to the database to see the value from `dataSnapshot.toString()` inside `onChildAdded`. How do you attach the `ValueEventListener` in your question (where udRef refers to) ?